# Authorizing google cloud endpoints API access without user sign in

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I understand how the authorization process with Oauth works but is it somehow possible to authorize my access to my endpoints API without the user having to sign in? So what I'm trying to do is to restrict access to my API so that only certain websites, that I allow, have access to it and no others.

In Google APIs console I have created a 'client ID for web applications'.

Comment: Who (or what) will be making the requests? Is it a person or another program?

Comment: What do you mean by "google cloud endpoints"? Do you mean Cloud Storage? Or Cloud SQL? Or do you just mean AppEngine endpoints for your own API?

Comment: @JudeOsborn Google Cloud Endpoints is a GAE feature (with it's very own tag as you see here). Check out the [docs](developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/).

Comment: @DanHolevoet basically the website is intended to be sort of bookshop. So I will use the API to store new books and for users to store/retrieve books they have selected. So it is a person making requests to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your described use case, the preferred solution *is* to use OAuth. In following the examples in the documentation, you'll be limiting the web sites (via the "JavaScript origins" value for the keys you obtained in the APIs Console).

Sites not listed in the origins will not be able to display the required authentication prompt (the client ID and origin are checked before Google will provide tokens). Developers will not be able to create their own client IDs with their preferred JavaScript origins, because your backend will be checking the client ID of the request is on a whitelist that is part of your code.

Comment: Thanks alot for taking time to answer. What I understand is that if I want to limit who can access my endpoints API my users will have to sign in using google+ and there is no other way. But I really don't need that.

So now I'm trying to make my own function to authenticate the website that is calling. How can I get the server name of website that made the call to the API? I've looked at the WebOb Request class but it doesn't seem to work with endpoints-proto-datastore(I'm following your and Danny Hermes's tutorial).

Comment: Dan, I don't think this answers his question. Gezim doesn't need client authentication and he also doesn't need client authorization. So no prompts to the user. I think he wants secure access to his backend and ensure no one can access his backend. The closest thing I can find is Service Accounts, but I see no documentation on how to implement it on the server side. Seems like it only works with Google APIs.

Comment: If a process is interacting with another process you want a service account, if you want a user interacting with a process, you want regular OAuth. Describing the problem in terms of a website (which has users) suggests the problem is the latter, not the former. Regardless, we do not document service accounts with Endpoints because it's not an officially supported use case currently.

Comment: I'm having the same problem: I've a client web app that uses some APIs that I have defined on my GAE application using Google Endpoints. The backend app doesn't have "human interface", it's only a "core". Users use the client web app to do stuffs, without logging in the app (because the app logic doesn't require that) but when a user perform a certain action I have to call a backend API, and doing that I need to say to the "core" that "I'm the right web app" because I don't want that someone else writes another web app that uses my core